# Написать программу, моделирующую кассы в магазине

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Доброго времени суток, Уважаемые Знатоки.

Сразу оговорюсь, помощь нужна не в решении задачи вместо меня. Просто не могу понять, как применить имеющиеся знания на практике. Если кто-нибудь поможет составить план действий, буду очень сильно благодарен.

Итак, вот сама задача:

*Напишите программу, моделирующую кассы в магазине. Существует несколько касс, работающих одновременно. Каждый покупатель — отдельный поток. Общее количество покупателей может быть больше, чем количество касс, но одновременно не может обрабатываться больше покупателей, чем имеется рабочих касс. У каждого покупателя есть набор товаров, которые должны быть выведены в процессе обслуживания.*

Comment: После первого предложения подумал, что мы в что где когда играем. Покупателя можно моделировать классом, реализующим интерфейс Runnable. А кассы пулом потоков. Кажется FixedThreadPool.

Comment: Всем откликнувшимся огромное спасибо.
Но можно как-то подкинуть ссылки на похожие примеры (особенно с FixedThreadPool).

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, как в комментарии написано примерно. Полагаю, что идея в том, что в каждом потоке должна быть очередь (т.е. очередь к каждой кассе), а также общий пул людей в магазине. И нужно равномерно заполнять эту очередь. Например, сделаем какую-то общую переменную - люди в магазине, и будем её увеличивать через какие-то промежутки времени (люди приходят в магазин). В то же время будем её уменьшать, когда человек закончил покупки и идет на кассу, кассу выбираем, исходя из размера очереди, где меньше - туда и идем.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно задачу сделать именно по ее условию (покупатель - отдельный поток). Иначе не зачтут, и придется переделывать ))).

Answer (score 0):

"Каждый покупатель - отдельный поток" - это очень странная (и вероятно неправильная) формулировка задачи. Логично было бы сказать, что каждая касса - отдельный поток, тогда на ум сразу приходят очереди, в которые встают покупатели, а кассы-потоки эти очереди разгребают.